# improving efficiency of R code using combination

Tags: r, performance

I have a data

data:

```
[1] "146002 1591246 1453825 1976867 318484"                                                                                                                             
[2] "669019 557068 787848 1752826 595490 1370072 32948 1059410 456048 2075616 2151636"                                                                                  
[3] "7052 84626 1876916 289198 1925401"                                                                                                                                 
[4] "2074708 609769 2074708 1586598 1750679"                                                                                                                            
[5] "230221 818400 230221 550378 569906 158775 178756"                                                                                                                  
[6] "357215 1000036 45393
```

I want to generate combination of these in such a way that cobination for each row is formed

for row 1

"146002 1591246","146002 145825","146002,1976867","1591246 1453825",...

combination of the five values together with a pair of two and this for all rows.

then i need to bind all these valued in a vector such that the final output looks like:

```
final output :
146002 1591246
146002 145825
.........
```

I am doing the following but its taking a lot of time:

```
 gram_2<-vector()
 for(i in 1:length(data))
 {
   if(length(unlist(strsplit(data[i]," ")))>2){
      comb<-combn(unlist(strsplit(data[i]," ")),2)
      for(j in 1:ncol(comb))
         {
          gram_2<-rbind(gram_2,paste(comb[,j],collapse=" "))
         }
      }
   gram_2<-rbind(gram_2,paste(data[i],collapse=" "))
 }
```

How could this be done efficiently ?thanks

Answer (score 1):

One line solution

```
apply(do.call(cbind, lapply(strsplit(data, " "), combn, 2)), 2, paste, collapse=" ")
```

Updated according to Ananda.

```
unlist(lapply(strsplit(data, " ", fixed=TRUE), combn, 2, paste, collapse=" "))
```

Comment: Not sure on the speed improvement, but `combn` has a `FUN` argument, allowing you to move the `paste` into the `combn` call itself (and thus eliminating the need for `do.call`).

Comment: Also, adding `fixed = TRUE` to `strsplit` generally leads to more efficient processing (if the pattern is fixed, which it appears to be here).

Comment: Thanks, I didn't know that combn has a FUN argument. :)

Comment: It's one of those often overlooked features :-)

Answer (score 0):

I thought pasting together would make the result less useful so constructed a two column matrix:

```
do.call(rbind, sapply( lapply( sapply(vec, strsplit, " "), combn, 2),t))
```

Comment: `t` is the matrix or data.frame transpose function.